# I'm trying to clear textarea after copying data from another textarea using jscript but unable to clear second textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<b>Q1.</b> 
<textarea readonly rows="4" columns="200" id="Q1_Old">Answer to be copied to second textarea</textarea>

<p>If the above answer is unchanged click on "Same Answer" for copying over, else click on "New Answer" to draft new answer</p>

<button onclick="SameAnswer()">Same Answer</button>
<input type="button" onclick="clearText()" value="New Answer">

<p><textarea readonly rows="4" columns="200" id="A1"></textarea>

<script>
function clearText() {
    document.getElementById("A1").reset();
}

function SameAnswer() {
   var x = document.getElementById("Q1_Old").value;
   document.getElementById("A1").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In the above code SameAnswer() function is working properly but ClearText() function isn't. Need help in resolving this issue

Comment: `document.getElementById("A1").value = ""`

Comment: innerHTML is not for inputs and reset is for forms.

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).reset is not a function"

Comment: @Hackerman, the problem with setting A1 to "" is that it can't use SameAnswer() function again.

Comment: @epascarello, can you please explain a further on innerHTML and how its effecting in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

reset is for an entire form. So you have two options.

1) set the value to empty string

```
document.getElementById("A1").value = "";
```

2) set the value to equal the default value

```
var ta = document.getElementById("A1");
ta.value = ta.defaultValue;
```

And when you are setting the value, you need to use value, not innerHTML.

```js
function clearText1() {
  var ta = document.getElementById("A1");
  ta.value = "";
  ta.removeAttribute("readOnly")    
}

function clearText2() {
  var ta = document.getElementById("A1")
  ta.value = ta.defaultValue;
  ta.removeAttribute("readOnly")    
}


function SameAnswer() {
   var x = document.getElementById("Q1_Old").value;
   var ta = document.getElementById("A1");
   ta.value = x;
   ta.setAttribute("readOnly", true)
}
```

```html
<b>Q1.</b> 
<textarea readonly rows="4" columns="200" id="Q1_Old">Answer to be copied to second textarea</textarea>

<p>If the above answer is unchanged click on "Same Answer" for copying over, else click on "New Answer" to draft new answer</p>

<button onclick="SameAnswer()">Same Answer</button>
<input type="button" onclick="clearText1()" value="New Answer 1">
<input type="button" onclick="clearText2()" value="New Answer 2">

<p><textarea readonly rows="4" columns="200" id="A1"></textarea>
```

Comment: Hey @epascarello, I tried your code and it helps me clearing and copying answer 'n' number of times, but I'm unable to edit the second textbox with my data. Can you help me establish an idea on editable text box for second one ?

Comment: You have the readonly field set so you can not edit it! So if someone is supposed to be able to edit it, you need to remove the readonly attribute. Edit question to set and remove the attribute.

Comment: I completely missed that I used readonly for my second textbox, thanks for pointing it out. (Y)

Answer (score 0):

Change .document.getElementById("A1").reset(); to document.getElementById("A1").value = "";

```js
function clearText() {
    document.getElementById("A1").value = "";
}

function SameAnswer() {
   var x = document.getElementById("Q1_Old").value;
   document.getElementById("A1").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<b>Q1.</b> 
<textarea readonly rows="4" columns="200" id="Q1_Old">Answer to be copied to second textarea</textarea>

<p>If the above answer is unchanged click on "Same Answer" for copying over, else click on "New Answer" to draft new answer</p>

<button onclick="SameAnswer()">Same Answer</button>
<input type="button" onclick="clearText()" value="New Answer">

<p><textarea readonly rows="4" columns="200" id="A1"></textarea>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, I think I need to understand a bit about innerHTML & forms.